# How can I make a text box in React which allows only numbers or an empty value, which triggers the number keypad on mobile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobile

There are lots of questions like this on StackOverflow, but none of them captures all of my requirements in the same solution. Any help appreciated.

### The problem

In my React app, I need a text box with the following characteristics:

1. It only allows digits to be entered - no minus signs, decimal places, letters, or anything besides just the digits 0-9.
2. It automatically brings up the number keypad on iOS and Android
3. I can further restrict the numbers that should be entered, e.g. only allow 4 digits
4. Leading zeroes are automatically trimmed, e.g. if a user types 02 it should correct to just 2
5. It allows an empty textbox, and can differentiate between empty and a value of 0

### Current code

https://codepen.io/micahrl/pen/RwGeLmo

This code allows typing non-digits, and will just interpret the value as NaN. For instance, the user can type `2f` or `asdf` and the page will say `You typed: NaN`.

Additionally, while the page loads initially with an empty text box, the user cannot type something and then delete it back to empty. Attempting to delete all text in the input box places a `0` in the box.

Finally, this code doesn't reliably trim leading zeroes, which causes me particular problems because I want to restrict the number to four digits. Typing `01` will not truncate the leading zero; on some browsers, typing `01111` will result in `1111`, which is good enough, while on others, typing `01111` will result in `0111`, which is a problem.

### What I've tried

Because I have set `type="number"` on the input element, if there is ever a non-number added to the text box, `event.target.value` in `setNumWrapper` will be an empty string. This means I can't differentiate between a true empty string (where the user has deleted all text) and invalid input (where the user has typed a non-number, like `asdf`).

I could set `type="text"` on the input element, except that I think I need to set it to `number` to get the number keypad on mobile OSes like iOS and Android.

Comment: For type `number`, you can check the `validity.badInput`,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState/badInput

Comment: @Keith that helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With further experimentation, and some help from @Keith in a comment, I've solved almost all my problems.

I've forked the codepen in my question and made these changes in the fork: https://codepen.io/micahrl/pen/GRjwqdO.

### Checking input validity

@Keith pointed me to `validity.badInput` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState/badInput). With this, I can differentiate between empty input, where a user types something then deletes it, and bad input, where the user attempts to add a non-numeric character.

That means I add this to the beginning of `setNumWrapper()`:

```js
    if (event.target.value === "") {
      if (event.target.validity.badInput) {
        // Set the text box and number to the old value - ignore the bad input
        inputRef.current.value = String(num);
        setNum(num);
      } else {
        // The data in the text box was deleted - set everything to empty
        inputRef.current.value = "";
        setNum(NaN);
      }
      return;
    }
```

I also have to make an `inputRef` with `useRef()`, and set it on the `<input>` element.

This solves #5 most of #1 (but see below for one remaining minor problem).

### Trimming leading zeroes

All I had to do for this was use that `inputRef` to set the value in the `<input>` element at the end of `setNumWrapper()`:

```js
inputRef.current.value = String(newNum);
```

The `<input>` element's value is always a string anyway, and casting the number to a string removed leading zeroes, if there were any.

### Remaining problem: invalid input is allowed if the text box is empty

When the text box is empty, the user can type non-numeric characters into it, and `setNumWrapper()` doesn't even fire. If you put a `console.log()` at the top of `setNumWrapper()`, it won't print anything to the log if the user types a letter, but it will print to the log if the user types a number.

This means I cannot use `setNumWrapper()` to solve this problem.

However, it's also relatively minor. On mobile, the number keypad comes up, preventing non-numeric input. On the desktop nothing stops the user from typing letters with their keyboard, but for my app, it's clear that only numbers are allowed, so this is good enough for now.

Still, if there's a way to fix this, I'd be curious to hear about it.